# How to edit the caption of the statistics in stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer

I would like to change the default caption of the summary statistics in stargazer. I don't want to omit it, just want to translate it, how do I do that?

In the package help, I didn't finy anything on the summary statistics, just on notes and the captions of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

`stargazer` can give you nice summary statistics when you put in a dataset instead of a regression model. You can specify the "caption" via `title`:

```
library("plm")
data("Produc", package = "plm")
stargazer(Produc, type="text", title="Descriptive statistics in any language?")

Descriptive statistics in any language?
===============================================================================
Statistic  N     Mean     St. Dev.     Min     Pctl(25)   Pctl(75)      Max    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
year      816 1,978.000    4.902      1,970     1,974      1,982       1,986   
pcap      816 25,036.660 27,780.400 2,627.120 7,096.657  27,691.570 140,217.300
hwy       816 10,218.420 9,253.597  1,827.140 3,857.863  11,266.550 47,699.420 
water     816 3,618.784  4,311.742   228.460   764.510   4,318.698  24,592.330 
util      816 11,199.450 14,768.870  538.490  2,488.327  11,598.470 80,728.140 
pc        816 58,188.290 59,770.780 4,052.710 21,651.390 64,796.270 375,341.600
gsp       816 61,014.320 69,973.900   4,354    16,502.5    68,126     464,550  
emp       816 1,747.101  1,855.988   108.300   475.025   2,114.100  11,258.000 
unemp     816   6.602      2.233      2.800     5.000      7.900      18.000   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```